# Diferencia de Fork y Branch Protected

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-fork

Me estoy iniciando en Git, pero me a surgido una duda.

Supongamos que tengo un un proyecto con la rama "origin" y otra rama "pruebas".

Si protejo la rama "origin" y solo doy acceso a "pruebas", que diferencia hay en que me colaboren en "pruebas", a que hagan un fork de mi repo y despues hagan pull request?

no es lo mismo?

solo tener acceso a la rama "pruebas" a hacer un fork del proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Bueno suponiendo que el repo es privado, al final creo si es lo mismo, hacer un fork y hacer pull request, a proteger la rama principal, dar acceso a la rama secundaria y desde ahii que me hagan merge request.